Generic points in ergodic dynamical systems.
Suppose that $(X, T, \mu)$ is an ergodic topological probability measure preserving dynamical system on a compact metric space $X.$ I want to show that almost every point in $X$ is $\mu$ generic.
Definition of a $\mu$-generic point $x$ is as follows:
A point $x$ is called $\mu$- generic if for every continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb R,$ we have that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) + f(T(x))+ \dots + f(T^n(x))}{n} = \int_X fd \mu$$
My thoughts were:
I feel like I can use that if $X$ is a compact metric space, then there exist a countable set of continuous functions $f_1: X \to \mathbb R, f_2: X \to \mathbb R, \dots $ such that for all $f: X \to \mathbb R$ continuous, there exists $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_k}(x) \to f(x)$ for every $x \in X.$
But I am not sure if I am correct or no or how can I use it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Do you know Birkhoff's ergodic theorem or you are supposed to come up with your own proof?

Yes I know it@MoisheKohan how can I prove it using Birkhoff's thm? Did you meant just like the answer below or something else?

See for instance here.

Indeed, you are on the right track. Here are some ideas: For $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, define $A(\phi)=A(\mu,T,\phi)$ to be the set of all those points along which the time average (relative to $T$) of $\phi$ converges to the space average (relative to $\mu$). Then the set of Birkhoff generic points for $(\mu,T)$ is
$$
\bigcap_{\phi}A(\phi).
$$
By the Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem, each $A(\phi)$ has full measure, but the intersection is not necessarily countable, so we can not at this stage conclude.
We are however given that $X$ is compact metric, thus there is a sequence $\phi_\bullet$ of continuous functions on $X$ that is dense (see e.g. $C(X)$ is separable when $X$ is compact?).
Claim: $\bigcap_{\phi}A(\phi)=\bigcap_{m\geq 1}A(\phi_m)$.
Proof: The $(\subseteq)$ part is syntactic. For $(\supseteq)$, let $x\in \bigcap_{m\geq 1}A(\phi_m)$, $\phi:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. By the density of $\phi_\bullet$, there is an $m$ such that $d_{C^0}(\phi,\phi_m)<\epsilon/3$. Since $x\in A(\phi_m)$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ such that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq N}$, one has
$$
\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi_m\circ T^k(x)-\mathbb{E}_\mu(\phi_m)\right|<\epsilon/3.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi\circ T^k(x)-\mathbb{E}_\mu(\phi)\right|&
\leq \left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi\circ T^k(x)-\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi_m\circ T^k(x)\right|\\
&\quad+\left|\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi_m\circ T^k(x)-\mathbb{E}_\mu(\phi_m)\right|\\
&\quad+\left|\mathbb{E}_\mu(\phi_m)-\mathbb{E}_\mu(\phi)\right|\\
&<\epsilon.
\end{align*}

What do you mean by syntactic?
